# How to get variable upper in the code

Tags: php, mysql, variables, position

I have a MySQL query in the `<body>` section of my website. I get certain variables with it - $power, $poles and so on.

How can I use this $variables in the `<head>` section for title, description and keywords?

...without making the whole this query again.

At the moment the code looks like this

```
<html>
<head>
...
<title>Данни за електродвигател <?php echo $Power; ?> kW <?php echo $Speed; ?> об./мин.</title>
...
</head>
<body>
...

    <?php require('config.php'); 
    $conn = mysql_connect (SQL_HOST,SQL_USER,SQL_PASS)
    or die ('cant connect to db');
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $conn);
    mysql_query('set names utf8', $conn);
    mysql_select_db(my_databas) or die('Could not select database');
    mysql_select_db("my_databas");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE 2` WHERE TYPE='".$_GET["TYPE2"]."'";
    $results = mysql_query($query)
    or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) 
    {
    extract($row);
    }
    ?>


<h2>Електродвигател <?php echo $TYPE; ?> </h2>
<div id="results">
    <h3>Тип по БДС IEC 60034:</h3>
    <table>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
    <td>Мощност:</td>
    <td><?php echo $Power; ?> kW</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Номинална скорост:</td>
    <td><?php echo $Speed; ?> об./мин.</td>
    </tr></table>
...
</body>
</html>
```

But the $variables in the TITLE stay empty :(

Comment: In the same way as you're currently using them in the body.

Comment: I added it. I dont want to make the same query at two places in the website

Comment: Execute your MySQL query *before* you start sending output to the client. If it is in the "body", it is probably too late.

Comment: sorry, I am absolute beginner. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute your php stuff at the very beginning & use values in `title`, `description` etc. accordingly. You don't necessarily have to execute your query within HMTL `body` part.

```
 <?php require('config.php'); 
    $conn = mysql_connect (SQL_HOST,SQL_USER,SQL_PASS)
    or die ('cant connect to db');
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $conn);
    mysql_query('set names utf8', $conn);
    mysql_select_db(my_databas) or die('Could not select database');
    mysql_select_db("my_databas");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE 2` WHERE TYPE='".$_GET["TYPE2"]."'";
    $results = mysql_query($query)
    or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) 
    {
    extract($row);
    }
    ?>

<html>
<head>
...
<title>Данни за електродвигател <?php echo $Power; ?> kW <?php echo $Speed; ?> об./мин.</title>
...
</head>
<body>
...



<h2>Електродвигател <?php echo $TYPE; ?> </h2>
<div id="results">
    <h3>Тип по БДС IEC 60034:</h3>
    <table>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
    <td>Мощност:</td>
    <td><?php echo $Power; ?> kW</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Номинална скорост:</td>
    <td><?php echo $Speed; ?> об./мин.</td>
    </tr></table>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I thought that this query should be placed just before the elements which will use its variables.

Answer (score 0):

you can use any PHP variable any where in the page. As you are beginner then good for you is to move your PHP code at the top  of the page and then use any variable in head or body.

```
 <?php require('config.php'); 
    $conn = mysql_connect (SQL_HOST,SQL_USER,SQL_PASS)
    or die ('cant connect to db');
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $conn);
    mysql_query('set names utf8', $conn);
    mysql_select_db(my_databas) or die('Could not select database');
    mysql_select_db("my_databas");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE 2` WHERE TYPE='".$_GET["TYPE2"]."'";
    $results = mysql_query($query)
    or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) 
    {
    extract($row);
    }
    ?>
 <html>
 <head>
  ...
<title>Данни за електродвигател <?php echo $Power; ?> kW <?php echo $Speed; ?> об./мин.
<!-- <title><?php echo $title; ?> <?php echo $Power; ?> kW <?php echo $Speed; ?> об./мин.
         ---- ^ -->
 </title>
  ...
 </head>
  <body>
  ...

 <h2>Електродвигател <?php echo $TYPE; ?> </h2>
<div id="results">
    <h3>Тип по БДС IEC 60034:</h3>
    <table>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
    <td>Мощност:</td>
    <td><?php echo $Power; ?> kW</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Номинална скорост:</td>
    <td><?php echo $Speed; ?> об./мин.</td>
    </tr></table>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You cant with PHP, but you can use javascript to dynamically alter  afterwards!

Comment: The original question was different, he asked if he could use variables in a single page above the query. After several edits this answer is wrong, but first I assumed he didnt have access to the head.